# jQuery tokeninput generates multiple inputs for 1 input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-tokeninput

I have a problem with jQuery tokeninput inputs, this is my ruby on rails code:

```
<% @free_preferences.each do |fp| %>
<% eventCriteria = EventCriteria.find_by_id(fp.event_criteria_id)%>
<% if !eventCriteria.is_exclusive? %>
    <% form_for fp do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :tag_tokens1, eventCriteria.name %>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_tokens1, "data-pre" => fp.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>

        <%= f.submit "Save preference", :disable_with => 'Saving preference...' %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <% form_for fp do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :tag_tokens2, eventCriteria.name %>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_tokens2, "data-pre" => fp.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>

        <%= f.submit "Save preference", :disable_with => 'Saving preference...' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And this is generated html source code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscription_preferences/128" class="edit_subscription_preference" id="edit_subscription_preference_128" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="bYJedYxgjjA+C+CWUkZpXH3mxNxOf8XPQgwp5/DEUp8=" /></div>  
        <label for="subscription_preference_tag_tokens1">Explicit include</label>
        <input data-pre="[{&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2012-03-20T08:48:53Z&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Windows xp&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:70,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2012-03-20T08:48:53Z&quot;}]" id="subscription_preference_tag_tokens1" name="subscription_preference[tag_tokens1]" size="30" type="text" />

<input data-disable-with="Saving preference..." id="subscription_preference_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save preference" />
```

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscription_preferences/129" class="edit_subscription_preference" id="edit_subscription_preference_129" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="bYJedYxgjjA+C+CWUkZpXH3mxNxOf8XPQgwp5/DEUp8=" /></div>  
        <label for="subscription_preference_tag_tokens2">Explicit exclude</label>
        <input data-pre="[]" id="subscription_preference_tag_tokens2" name="subscription_preference[tag_tokens2]" size="30" type="text" />

<input data-disable-with="Saving preference..." id="subscription_preference_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save preference" />
```

It seems good but the problem is that for each subscription_preference_tag_tokensX input four jQuery tokeninputs are created, if I check with firebug this is the code:

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscription_preferences/128"  class="edit_subscription_preference" id="edit_subscription_preference_128" method="post">
<div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;   padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display:       inline; ">

<label for="subscription_preference_tag_tokens1">Explicit include</label>
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">

<input data-pre="[{"updated_at":"2012-03-20T08:48:53Z","name":"Windows xp","id":70,"created_at":"2012-03-20T08:48:53Z"},{"updated_at":"2012-03-13T10:01:10Z","name":"something","id":59,"created_at":"2012-03-13T10:01:10Z"}]" id="subscription_preference_tag_tokens1" name="subscription_preference[tag_tokens1]" size="30" type="text" style="display: none; "/>

<input data-disable-with="Saving preference..." id="subscription_preference_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save preference"/>

</form>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscription_preferences/129" class="edit_subscription_preference" id="edit_subscription_preference_129" method="post">
<div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display: inline; ">

<label for="subscription_preference_tag_tokens2">Explicit exclude</label>
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook">

<input data-pre="[]" id="subscription_preference_tag_tokens2" name="subscription_preference[tag_tokens2]" size="30" type="text" style="display: none; "/>
<input data-disable-with="Saving preference..." id="subscription_preference_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save preference"/>
</form>
```

I don't know why ir creates four 'token-input-list-facebook' for each "subscription_preference_tag_tokensX". This is a picture of the problem:

[image]

EDIT 1:

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
  $('#subscription_preference_tag_tokens1').tokenInput('/tags.json', { 
    crossDomain: false, 
    preventDuplicates: true,
    prePopulate: $('#subscription_preference_tag_tokens1').data('pre'),
    theme: 'facebook',

  });
  $('#subscription_preference_tag_tokens2').tokenInput('/tags.json', { 
    crossDomain: false, 
    preventDuplicates: true,
    prePopulate: $('#subscription_preference_tag_tokens2').data('pre'),
    theme: 'facebook',

  });

});
```

Comment: Can you post some of your javascript code?

Comment: Hi mosch, I edited my question, you can find javascript code at the end of the post.